# python / pandas - reading csv with text before data, to dataframe

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to figure out how to load up a bunch of climate files to a dataframe that are in the following format:  [image]

You can see how there is all that text up to row 26, and then the data starts..

I have about 50 files that look like this, and I'll have to loop through them via OS.   I tried using an IO String reader like this, but not having any love with it.  It throws this:

> "CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 2 fields in
>   line 26, saw 27"

```
data = pd.DataFrame()
temp = []
s = StringIO()

for (dirname, dirs, files) in os.walk('.'):
        for fle in files:
            with open(fle) as f:
                for line in f:                    
                        s.write(line)
            s.seek(0) # "rewind" to the beginning of the StringIO object
            x = pd.read_csv(s) # with further parameters…
            break
```

Thanks! KC

Comment: Did you try using the built in `skiplines` argument in `pandas`?

Comment: duhhhh duhhhh.   thank you...

Comment: this usually happens if you have a variable number of delimiters. why do you "rewind" to 0 and not to the beginning of your actual data?

Comment: Dmitry's response nailed it.  it works

Comment: Also in case you ever encounter problems, here is a quick shell command that will do it as well `sed -e '1,25d' < data.txt` where the numbers specify the range of rows to omit, where the last number is inclusive.

Comment: I went through it, but I'm still having issues pulling in the data...   I'm not sure if this is actually a CSV (even though it was downloaded as one...).   any suggetions?